# Load JSON from server using jQuery and display it in html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html5

I am just starting with JavaScript and jQuery, so I appreciate your help!

I want to read items from a JSON file like this:

```
{
  "items": [
    "this",
    "that"
  ]
}
```

My code (inspired by a number of stackoverflow and jQuery reference example code) looks like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="notification"></div>
<ul id="items"></ul>
<script>
$.get('list.json', {}, function(data, response){
   var jsonResult;
   try {
     jsonResult = JSON.parse(data);
   }
   catch (e) {
     $('div#result').html('<span style="color:red">cannot load data because: "'+e+'"</span>');
   };

     var items = []
     $.each( jsonResult['items'], function( key, val ) {
        items.push( "<li id='item-" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
     });

     /* // this does not work
    $( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
    }).appendTo( "div#notification" );
      */

     $('ul#items').html(items.join(""));

 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And it works. Yay.

My questions:

- Is that more or less ok what I nitted? What can be enhanced?
- Why does the commented-out section not work? I took this from https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some ideas:

`#1`- I suggest using `.map().join()` or even better `.reduce()` which is more semantically correct for what you want to do: reduce a array to an html string.

`#2` - You should also use `var jsonResult = {items: []};` otherwise if the `catch` gets called you will have a error down the line because you expect  `jsonResult` to be an Object.

`#3` - Another thing: I suppose your example is simplified so much it became incorrect, since the `items` array has strings, and not objects with `key` and `val`...

```
{
  "items": [
    "this",
    "that"
  ]
}
```

`#4`- You did have an error in your code, you were using `function( key, val ) {`, but that is not the jQuery API. The callback gets the iterated item as `this` and in the second argument. The first argument is the `index`...

You could use a callback with destructuring like this:

```
 var items = []
 $.each(jsonResult['items'], function(i, {key, val}){
    items.push( "<li id='item-" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
 });
```

Improved code suggestion:

```js
$.get('list.json', {}, function(data, response) {
  var jsonResult = {items: []};
  try {
    jsonResult = JSON.parse(data);
  } catch (e) {
    $('div#result').html('<span style="color:red">cannot load data because: "' + e + '"</span>');
  };

  var html = jsonResult['items'].reduce(function(string, item) {
    return string + "<li id='item-" + item.key + "'>" + item.val + "</li>"
  }, '');

  $('ul#items').html(html);

});
```

`#5` - About your commented code question:

You are trying to use `.join()` on objects. It does work if you fix what I suggested above([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/0gkmxbm5/)).

Comment: thank you. one question: Can't I have an array of simple strings in the json file? The key (in my code) becomes indices then.

Comment: jQuery also has a `getJSON` method that avoids the need to constantly write a try-catch block. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: @steffen you can have just strings in you JSON. In that case you can use `function( key, val ) {` where `key` is the numeric index.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto true. And I think the OPs question has code from those docs.